# SUMPRODUCT with SUMIFS

Tags: excel

```
=SUMIFS($B:$B*$N:$N,$N:$N,">=5",$N:$N,"<10")
```

I want to multiply 2 columns and sum all instances of it, conditioned only on one of the columns.The formula gives an error because I multiply in the first argument, which just should be a single number I guess. I tried using **SUMPRODUCT** too, but as column B does not have a condition, it doesn't work. Can anyone advice please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent `SUMPRODUCT` formula for your `SUMIFS` attempt is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B:B,N:N,--(N:N>=5)*(N:N<10))
```

But you should avoid using full column references in `SUMPRODUCT`. If you can't limit range sizes, consider using dynamic named ranges.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B:B,IF(N:N>=5,IF(N:N<10,N:N,""),""))
```

with array ctrl+shift+enter